# Send notify to member when group has been deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, push-notification

In my app, I want to push notification to members of group when group has been deleted by admin, but I have a problem, I save member of this group by using this : `group_members = @group.users` 
but when group has been deleted, this `group_members` become `nil` so I can't push notify to them. Can some one give me an ideal how to save those member? thank alot
this is my controller

```
class Admin::GroupsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :load_group

  def destroy
    group_members = @group.users
    if @group.destroy
      notify_to_group_members group_members
      flash[:success] = t "flash.delete_success", record: Group.name
    else
      flash[:danger] = t "flash.delete_fail", record: Group.name
    end
    binding.pry
    redirect_to admin_company_management_groups_path
  end

  private
  def notify_to_group_members members
    members.each do |member|
      message = Aws::Sns::GeneratePayload.call I18n.t("company.push_messages.group.delete"),
        action: :delete, type: :group, device: member.device
      Aws::Sns::PublishToEndpoint.delay.call member, message
    end
  end

  def load_group
    @group = Group.find_by_id params[:id]
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a dependent condition on destroy to destroy the users if the group is destroyed?

Comment: no, i only have a dependent condition on destroy to destroy the users_group if the group is destroyed

Comment: Add a callback `before_destroy :notify_to_group_members`l and move `notify_to_group_members` to your Group model.

Comment: if i do that, will notify still send to member when group cant destroy for some reason? or it will roll back notify send method? i not sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to duplicate `@group.users`:

```
group_members = @group.users.dup
```

This way `group_members` won't point to the original object, which will later be destroyed.

You can also wrap this in a transaction in case `@group` doesn't destroy:

```
group_members = @group.users.dup
if @group.transaction do
    @group.destroy
    notify_to_group_members group_members
  end
  flash[:success] = t "flash.delete_success", record: Group.name
else
  flash[:danger] = t "flash.delete_fail", record: Group.name
end
```

Comment: it not work, i still got nil in notify_to_group method

Comment: Updated answer - you can also use a transaction to do a rollback in case `@group` has errors and isn't destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You have different ways to do this, but a "Rails like way to accomplish this is by using callbacks. The before_destroy callback occurs right after any validation and before the actual destroy happens.

You could do this in your model (assuming you are using ActiveRecord):

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Add a before destroy callback
  # This will be called just before the group (and the dependent members are destroyed)
  before_destroy :notify_to_group_members

  # Rest of your methods

  private
  def notify_to_group_members
    members.each do |member|
      message = Aws::Sns::GeneratePayload.call I18n.t("company.push_messages.group.delete"),
        action: :delete, type: :group, device: member.device
      Aws::Sns::PublishToEndpoint.delay.call member, message
    end
  end
end
```

And then your controller would be "dry" as the notification logic is in the Group model.

```
class Admin::GroupsController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :load_group

  def destroy
    group_members = @group.users
    if @group.destroy
      flash[:success] = t "flash.delete_success", record: Group.name
    else
      flash[:danger] = t "flash.delete_fail", record: Group.name
    end
    binding.pry
    redirect_to admin_company_management_groups_path
  end

  private

  def load_group
    @group = Group.find_by_id params[:id]
  end
end
```

This way, you are sure that your members are being notified and that the group is deleted.

Comment: if i do that, will notify still send to member when group cant destroy for some reason? or it will roll back notify send method? i not sure about this.

Comment: It will not send the notification. The notification only sends when all validation are true and the Group will delete. Give it a try!

Comment: Could you try this answer?